# Getting system date in the correct local format?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, system, date-format

Is there any way I can retrieve the phones system date format, eg: dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx).

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object.

```
 DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

According to the documentation (in link) it will display the date in the current date format.

For the actual format

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work?

```
var formattedddMMyyyy = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formattedMMddyyyy = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```